# ASP.NET MVC DropDownList alternative

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, forms, drop-down-menu

I'm using a dropdownlist for a field on a form, but with large amount of data retrieving from the server, makes the load of the page extremely slow. Do you have a solution to this problem?

Comment: ...don't load so much data at once. Don't overload your users. If I have to stare at a dropdownlist with thousands of items I immediately close the tab and leave the website (or complain to the UX guys if I am _told_ to use the website).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually, this is an Intranet App, where the Seller records his sale, he must select a Customer in a list of thousands, so I can't avoid to give the list to the user. I know the dropdownlist is imposilbe to use in this case, but I don't know any other "BUILT-IN" solution in asp.net mvc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implement a free text like solution like:

- when the user clicks on the text input you can pop up a dialog to query the users (you can add an additional search field and then load in a table the results, add a click on a row should add the user to the main form)
- true free text expirience with deferred loading the matches like Facebook search does

Comment: Thank you, your solution seems to be what I'm looking for, specially the first one. Now, how would I pass the selected value to the main form, without changing the other values I filled previously in that form?